# Fixed Header And Footer For GridView

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have a gridview and for client side sorting i am using the Jquery [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-key.html) plugin. Now i want the header and footer of the grid to be fixed and the rows to be scrolled.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can create three divs header content footer 
where header can have the column names and fixed height and same styling with footer, in the content div give a bigger height and put the gridview inside it then add overflow = auto , here you can scroll the gridview in the content div while maintaining the header and footer

```
<div id="header">Columns</div>
<div id="content">GridView</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: is there any JQuery plugin which does both fixed header and soring?

Comment: You can simply google it, I found this http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fixedtableheader, I found good results with "fixed table headers in jQuery" search keyword.